# One particular Unanswered question with my tags has been answered, upvoted 5 times and not downvoted?

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions, my-tags

In the screenshot below from https://gis.stackexchange.com/unanswered I have set **Unanswered** and then **my tags**.

[image]

All is good until I click on the [second (indicated) question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115028/repeating-steps-based-on-different-field-using-modelbuilder) (below) which clearly has a nett upvoted answer (and so should not be class as unanswered by any definition that I have seen).

[image]
Is there any way that this can be the expected result, or is it a bug?

Comment: This is a bug, caused by the merge. That upvoted answer was originally posted under [another question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115853/iterating-model-over-multiple-fields-using-modelbuilder).